# Remove watermarks from the images using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I wanted to detect and delete watermarks from the images using python. I have tried opencv but couldn't make it. Below is the sample image. Here time is watermark on all images.
[Image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NckG.png)

Sample code attached

```
#coding:utf-8
import os
import os.path
#import Image

def hasBlackAround(x, y, distance, img):
    w, h = img.size
    startX = 0 if x - distance < 0 else x - distance
    startY = 0 if y - distance < 0 else y - distance
    endX = w - 1 if x + distance > w - 1 else x + distance
    endY = h - 1 if y + distance > h - 1 else y + distance
    hasBlackAround = False
    for j in range(startX, endX):
        for k in range(startY, endY):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel((j, k))
            #if r < 130 and g < 130 and b < 130:
            if r >= 255 and g >= 255 and b >= 255:

               return True
   return False

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("E:/Projects/Analysis/unnamed.png")
w, h = img.size
rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')
for x in range(0, w - 1):
   for y in range(0, h - 1):
       if not hasBlackAround(x, y, 1, rgb_im):
           rgb_im.putpixel((x, y), (255,255,255))
rgb_im.save("E:/Projects/Analysis/1_output_v1.jpg")
```

Additional Information about Images:
1. It is always bottom left corner
2. It is transparent
3. Color is always the same

Comment: Add your own code to the post.

Comment: This is too broad and the question shows some lack of work. Some possible questions: position always bottom-left? Looks intransparent, right? Color always the same? You want to do it for aesthetics or for not allowing someone to see the date (huge effect on techniques)? And so on... If aesthetics + intransparent + color + fixed-pos: search for this fixed-color; mask them, use inpainting (e.g. using scikit-image).

Comment: @Zissouu this is for my academic and research project

Answer (score 0):

Inpainting technique reconstructs the image by filling any gaps in the image.

Please try the inpainting method in opencv:

```
cv2.inpaint()
```

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html